# Mootools 1.6 Subclass initialize method is not called

Tags: javascript, inheritance, mootools, extends, mootools-more

I'm using mootools 1.6. 
I based my code on their tutorial but when I try to run it, the `initialize` function of my subclass is not invoked. Instead, it goes directly to the parent class' `initialize` function.
I tried breakpointing inside the subclass `initialize` function but it really doesn't go there. In fact, my additional functions are also undefined. It's like only the functions of the parent class are created. :(

Here's my sample code:

parent.js

```
   var Parent = new Class({

    initialize: function(){
        alert("parent");
    },
    ...

});
```

child.js

```
var Child = new Class ( {
    Extends: Parent, 
    initialize: function () {
        this.parent();
        alert("child");
    },
    ... some additional functions
});
```

1.) Note that they are in different js files.
2.) These files are preloaded by cocos2d-js

```
    ...
    "src/controllers/parent.js",
    "src/controllers/child.js",
    ...
```

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with `1.6`. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/otdfddyd/ but maybe you have a problem with the loader you are using. Can you adapt my jsFiddle to reproduce your problem?

Comment: sorry i'm new to javascript. Will it make a difference if I put them all in one file? My objects are in different files.

Comment: hi Sergio, I already know what's causing the problem. I had another file, child2.js using the same object name for the child.  I'm not using that file anymore but since it's listed in the resources after the child.js, it's redefining the object. And that's why it's not going to the child class' initialization. i'm sorry about this. Thanks for your help, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue. There's no issue with Mootools. It was how I used it. I'm posting it for people who might encounter the same issue.

I have 3 js files.

```
parent.js
child.js
orphan.js (calling it orphan hahaha)
```

These 3 files are added to project.json in that order. I'm not using `orphan.js`. I thought I already removed it from the list but I was wrong. :(

Inside `orphan.js`, is a class. This class uses the same name as the class inside `child.js`. It's empty and is just extending the parent. What happened was, it redefined the object since it's loaded after `child.js`. 
I switched their order to see if it will use `child.js` declaration instead and indeed, it did. But that's not the solution. I just used it to prove that it was redefined. The solution was to remove that file from source / make sure no classes have the same name.

Whew. false alarm.

Comment: there is no value in this question or answer as it's not tagged correctly and does not highlight how you load your files so it will just send people down the wrong path - there is nothing wrong with mootools class inheritance.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get your comment. I already informed in my question that I'm preloading the files using cocos2djs. For cocos2djs, you need to list your files in the resources array.